# SFML Access violation

Tags: c++, exception, sfml, access-violation

I'm making a tetris game in C++ and in the DrawBoard() function I'm getting an error that reads:
Exception thrown at 0x0F52DA36 (sfml-graphics-d-2.dll) in Tetris_C++.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x013EDA88.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Here's the code:

```
void DrawBoard() {

for (int i = 0; i < boardWidth; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < boardHeight; i++)
    {
        switch (board[i][j]) {//What's wrong with this?
        case 'b':
            squares[i][j].setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
            break;
        case 'c':
            squares[i][j].setFillColor(sf::Color::Cyan);
            break;
        case 'y':
            squares[i][j].setFillColor(sf::Color::Yellow);
            break;
        case 'o':
            squares[i][j].setFillColor(sf::Color(255, 165, 0));//Orange
            break;
        case 'p':
            squares[i][j].setFillColor(sf::Color(150, 50, 250));//Purple
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

for (int x = 0; x < boardWidth; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < boardHeight; y++) {
        window.draw(squares[x][y]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Without knowing what are `board` and `squares`, nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The error simply means that your program tried to access memory outside its allocated address space. 
But without seeing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) it's impossible to know where your error is. A *guess* would be that one of your variables have gone out of scope or that you are trying to access outside the bounds of your `squares` array - but again, that's only a guess based on incomplete info.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int j = 0; j < boardHeight; i++)
```

this is what makes you get a segmentation fault (im sure its a typo)

you only get 1 iterate for your outer loop, and then the inner loop makes the segfault by incrementing `i` until it is become equal to `boardwidth`

the code is self explanatory, so im sure this should be:

```
for (int j = 0; j < boardHeight; j++)
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo and everything works fine now.